# Add filter functionality to Workbox

Tags: workbox

I would like to add the possibility to filter the items in the workbox of Siecore 9.3 by the current logged in user. The advanced version would be to select a user in a dropdown but that is optional.
I have already added the filter checkbox to the workbox by adding it in the core database.

[image]

And I already have some custom functionality for the workbox.

Workbox.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<control xmlns:def="Definition" xmlns="http://schemas.sitecore.net/Visual-Studio-Intellisense">
  <Workbox>
    <Favicon Src="/sitecore/images/favicon.ico" runat="server" />
    <CodeBeside Type="Company.Sc.Application.Extension.CMS.ContentEditor.Workbox.WorkboxForm,Company.Sc.Application.Extension"/>
    <Stylesheet Src="Content Manager.css" DeviceDependant="true"/>
    <Stylesheet Src="Ribbon.css" DeviceDependant="true"/>
    <Stylesheet Src="Workbox.css" DeviceDependant="true"/>
    <Stylesheet Src="/sitecore/shell/themes/navigator.css"/>
    <Script Src="/sitecore/shell/Applications/Content Manager/Content Editor.js"/>

    <Stylesheet Key="Workbox">
      html { width:100%; height:100% }
      body { width:100%; height:100%; overflow:auto }
      #States table { width: 100%; }
    </Stylesheet>

    <FormPage Application="Workbox" Title="Workbox">

      <input type="hidden" id="scActiveRibbonStrip" name="scActiveRibbonStrip" />

      <Border ID="Grid">

        <Border ID="RibbonPanel"/>

        <Border Class="scGreyBackground scStretchAbsolute scWorkboxContentContainer">

          <Border ID="Grid2">
            
            <Border ID="States">
            </Border>
          
          </Border>
          
        </Border>

      </Border>

        
    </FormPage>
  </Workbox>
</control>
```

and the WorkboxForm.cs:

```
    using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Annotations;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls;
using Sitecore.Workflows;
using Sitecore.Workflows.Simple;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace Company.Sc.Application.Extension.CMS.ContentEditor.Workbox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extended workbox for us
    /// </summary>
    public class WorkboxForm : Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Workbox.WorkboxForm
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// Extended display State
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="workflow">workflow</param>
        /// <param name="state">state</param>
        /// <param name="stateItems">stateItems</param>
        /// <param name="control">control</param>
        /// <param name="offset">offset</param>
        /// <param name="pageSize">pagesize</param>
        protected override void DisplayState(IWorkflow workflow, WorkflowState state, StateItems stateItems, Control control, int offset, int pageSize)
        {
            base.DisplayState(workflow, state, stateItems, control, offset, pageSize);
            foreach (Control ctrl in control.Controls)
            {
                try
                {
                    ID id = this.GetIDFromXml(ctrl);
                    Item item = Database.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(id);
                    if (item != null)
                    {
                        (ctrl as XmlControl)["Path"] = item.Paths.FullPath;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the item.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="xmlCtrl">The control.</param>
        /// <returns>The item</returns>
        private ID GetIDFromXml(Control xmlCtrl)
        {
            ID id = ID.Null;
            string click = (xmlCtrl as XmlControl)["Click"].ToString();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(click))
            {
                string[] param = click.Replace("Open", string.Empty).Trim('(', ')').Split(',');
                id = ID.Parse(param[0].Trim(' ', '"'));
            }

            return id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// neccessity because base class of this (WorkboxForm) contains reflection logic
        /// that tries invoking a same named private method that is otherwise not found and leads
        /// to a "method not found" error ( RW-332 )
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">The WorkflowPipelineArgs.</param>
        [UsedImplicitly]
        private void WorkflowCompleteStateItemCount(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
        {
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var type = this.GetType().BaseType;
            MethodInfo method = null;
            method = type.GetMethod("WorkflowCompleteStateItemCount", bindingFlags, Type.DefaultBinder, new Type[] { args.GetType() }, null);
            if (method != null && !method.DeclaringType.Equals(this.GetType()))
            {
                method.Invoke(this, new object[] { args });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The question is how I can reload the page as soon as the checkbox is clicked so only the filtered items are shown and the checkbox is still checked and as soon as the checkbox is unchecke all the items in the draft state are shown again.